# Pluggable architecture of nopcommerce

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I want to create a pluggable architecture for my ERP project. I want to adopt the approach of nopcommerce, can anyone explain how it works please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the sources like recommended on nopCommerce community forums?

Question asked by you: [Plugin architecture](https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/49011/plugin-architecture.aspx)

or

Question asked by you on GitHub: [pluggable architecture](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/2480)

---

Anyway, here's a shortage on how it works

The method Initialize of PluginManager gets called pre application start.
This due to the attribute of PluginManager

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PluginManager), "Initialize")]
```

Initialize() then will load all Description.txt located in the ~/Plugins (default) folder and its sub directories.

If a plugin is compatible with current nopCommerce version it shadow copy the plugin DLL and its dependencies (other DLLs) and loads it using BuildManager.